# Analytic function $f$ either constant or surjective on unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on unit disk and continuous on it. Assume $|f(z)|=1$ on $\{x;|x|=1\}$. Then $f$ is constant or $f(U)=U$ where $U=\{x;|x|<1\}$.

My attempt:

By maximum principle, $|f(z)|\leq 1$ on $U$. Suppose $f(U)\neq U$. Then there exists $z_0\in U$ such that $z_0\notin f(U)$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{f(z)-z_0}
$$
is analytic on unit disk. By using maximum principle, then
$$
\left|\frac{1}{f(z)-z_0}\right|\leq \frac{1}{1-z_0}
$$
on $U$. Thus,
$$
|f(z)-z_0|\geq 1-|z_0|
$$
which implies that
$$
f(D)\in U\setminus \{z;|z-z_0|< 1-z_0\}
$$
We can take $z_1\in \{z;|z-z_0|< 1-z_0\}$ such that 
$$
|z_1|<|z_0|.
$$
By same argument, on $U$,
$$
|f(z)-z_1|\geq 1-|z_1|.
$$
Hence, we can find $|z_n|\rightarrow 0$ such that on $U$
$$
|f(z)-z_n|\geq 1-|z_n|.
$$
Then we have
$$
|f(z)|\geq 1-2|z_n|\rightarrow 1.
$$
Hence, $|f(z)|=1$ on $U$. $f$ is constant by using argument of open mapping theorem.

Is this approach correct? I am not sure about $z_n$.

Comment: Although you have constructed a sequence $z_n$ that has strictly decreasing magnitude, as written you have not shown in converges to zero specifically.

Comment: @eyeballfrog if i take $z_1=z_0-\frac{1-|z_0|}{2}\frac{z_0}{|z_0|}$, then $z_n$ should converges to $0$. Is that enough?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116965/show-that-f-maps-the-entire-unit-disc-onto-itself for some solutions.

Comment: @MartinR thanks a lot

Comment: @whereamI Yes. In fact, it reaches zero in a finite number of steps, since once $|z_n| < 1/2$ you can choose $z_{n+1} = 0$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you are right. That's good. Thank you very much